# Not installing haxm in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, haxm

I installed sdk in Android Studio

But I download haxm but it does not install

Error : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bearg.jpg)

Comment: You say it does not install, but then you show a message saying it was installed successfully.  What exactly do you mean that "it does not install"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing on Mac M1chip, then that's probably the case it will not work.

If you don't use MAC then please try

1. Download directly from https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager
2. Go to this url and check the configuration https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Windows-Installation-Environment-Check-and-Configurations

Comment: No, I do not work with Mac